# Extract color name from a System.Windows.Media.Color

Tags: wpf

How do I extract the name of a color (e.g. "green") from a System.windows.Media.Color object? The `.tostring()` method gives me the hex format #ff008000.

Comment: [This](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32386/what-colour-is-this) might be of interest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use reflection to get the color names:

```
static string GetColorName(Color col)
{
    PropertyInfo colorProperty = typeof(Colors).GetProperties()
        .FirstOrDefault(p => Color.AreClose((Color)p.GetValue(null), col));
    return colorProperty != null ? colorProperty.Name : "unnamed color";
}
```

The following code shows how to use `GetColorName()`:

```
Color col = new Color { R = 255, G = 255, B = 0, A = 255 };
MessageBox.Show(GetColorName(col)); // displays "Yellow"
```

Please note that the above `GetColorName()` method is not very fast, since it uses reflection. If you plan to make many calls to `GetColorName()`, you probably should cache the color table in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In the WPF, the hex code stands just as it were rgba.

```
#ff008000
```

Would be

```
rgba(255, 0, 80, 0); // last 2 00s are for alpha filter.
```

If that's the result. You should use switch statement to convert it to some String value. Also, `.ToString()` method doesn't generate a Human readable String result like `Green`. It just converts the result to a String while passing the value to methods and function that would require a String argument.

The following code would do the trick for you:

```
var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
var brush = (Brush) converter.ConvertFromString("#ff008000");
```

Use the `brush` now.

Comment: Thanks! As I "speak" VB I had to "translate" C# into VB, and it worked fine:

Comment: Oh, hehe I never knew you were working with VB. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

My Visual Basic translation is like this:

```
   Function GetColorName(ByVal col As System.Windows.Media.Color) As String

    Dim coltype As System.Type = GetType(System.Windows.Media.Colors)
    Dim colproplist() As PropertyInfo = coltype.GetProperties

    Try

        Dim colorproperty As PropertyInfo = colproplist.FirstOrDefault(Function(p As PropertyInfo) Color.AreClose(p.GetValue(col, Nothing), col))

        Return colorproperty.Name

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return ("unnamed color")

    End Try

End Function
```

I had to catch a nullreference exception, when executing this function with an unnamed color. Why, I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the English color name if it is defined:

```
Function GetName(color As Media.Color) As String
  Dim c = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B)
  Return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(c)
End Function
```