# how to change to string color name from System.Windows.SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey?

Tags: c#, wpf, systemcolors, high-contrast

Is there some way to get color names such as Red, Black etc. from **System.Windows.SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey** in WPF code behind?

```
       string color = "Black";
       if (System.Windows.SystemParameters.HighContrast)
       {                    
          color = System.Windows.SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey; // I want to get color from this value
       }
```

Comment: `System​Colors.WindowTextBrush.Color.ToString()` would return `"#FF000000"`. Maybe that's sufficient.

Comment: This will give you the name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468848/1136211

Answer (score 0):

It depends. `SystemColors.WindowTextBrush` will give you the `Brush`. You could then check wheter its string representation matches any of the `Brushes` returned from the static properties the `Brushes` class:

```
string color = "Black";
if (System.Windows.SystemParameters.HighContrast)
{
    System.Windows.Media.Brush brush = System.Windows.SystemColors.WindowTextBrush;
    string s = brush.ToString();
    color = typeof(System.Windows.Media.Brushes).GetProperties()
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetValue(null)?
        .ToString() == s)?
        .Name;
}
```