# WPF &XAML: How to bind Color property to Brush

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'am trying to set the background of a textblock:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="Teams" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key = "teamColor" Color="{Binding TeamColor}"/>
                    <!--This below doesn't work either..-->
                    <!--<SolidColorBrush x:Key = "teamColor" Color="Aqua"/>-->
                </DataTemplate.Resources>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TeamName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{Binding teamColor}"/>

                    <!--Binding with the viewModel color property works, since the textblock below displays the team's color-->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TeamColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>  
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Since, if I define an exact color (see the commented line- Color = Aqua) and the textblock's background still remain white, i assume the given solidcolorbrush which is defined in the datatemplate.resources is cannot be used to set the textblock's background color.

What am I missing?

Comment: 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'

Comment: Ahh, sorry, copy / paste error. Clemens has what I was trying to get at in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Background="{Binding teamColor}"
```

makes no sense, because there is no `teamColor` property.

It should be

```
Background="{StaticResource teamColor}"
```

---

Or without a resource declaration:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TeamName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding TeamColor}"/>
    </TextBlock.Background>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: None of this works. The XAML parsed without problem, but the color of the textblock remain white

Comment: Perhaps your TeamColor property has the wrong type. It should be `System.Windows.Media.Color`. Are there any data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio?

Comment: Now I'm using the System.Windows.Media.Color. The textblock is still white, however,  the text in the color's  textblock (<TextBlock Text="{Binding TeamColor}") is now give the stored color in HTML

Comment: We can't tell when you don't show us the relevant parts of your code, i.e. the view model property declaration and value assignment.

Comment: To get the color name from a `System.Windows.Media.Color` you would have to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468671/extract-color-name-from-a-system-windows-media-color) inside an `IValueConverter`.